# Clark County Nevada Parcel GIS data

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for Clark County Nevada Parcel GIS data. The data format can be in any type of geospatial format. shapefile,kml,geojson, etc...

Their county gis department has a ton of data http://www.clarkcountynv.gov/gis/services/Pages/FreeGISData.aspx
but they do not seem to have parcel data for download. I have also OSM data for the entire state of nevada, which has a ton of data including building outlines, but I cannot find parcels.

I am getting the feel that I will have to pay for this data but I do not want to do this. If anybody knows of any resources how to obtain this data that would extremely helpful.

I know Python and can somewhat tinker with javascript so if there is a way to pull the data off the web I may be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the highlighted section above the listings, there is a layers file download that has parcels.lyr in it.
beware: its not open data because arcgis esri isn't open source. you either have to use their software or find a way to convert it.
i know of a number of ways to get open data from esri, but have not found a good lyr file converter to date.
[layers file](https://mapsrv.clarkcountynv.gov/pub/layers.zip)

EDIT:
if you dig through the ftp site, you'll find [crpcl](https://mapsrv.clarkcountynv.gov/pub/crpcl/)...the pcl caught my eye. download the zip with shapefiles and xlsx with data definitions. that is parcel data too.

Comment: i have arcmap, i downloaded the link you provided but it has those red exclamation marks when I open the data. and there is no local data source to connect it to...

Comment: i avoid arcgis and esri like the plague so i have no frame of reference to help you out. maybe ask the county? or go to gis.stackexchange.com and ask them. the data is there.